# SQL Running Total using CROSS JOIN

Tags: sql, join, cross-join

Need running total of a table based on date and another column. Say I have the following table called Sales:

```
Day      Client

1        Smith, J
3        Johnson, B
6        Fuller, A
7        Smith, J
8        Johnson, B
9        Lee, M
```

I run the following query:

```
SELECT a.Day, a.Client, SUM(1) AS RunningTotal
FROM Sales a CROSS JOIN Sales b
WHERE (b.Day <= a.Day) 
GROUP BY a.Day, a.Client
ORDER BY a.Day
```

This gives me the following:

```
Day Client       RunningTotal

1   Smith, J     1
3   Johnson, B   2
6   Fuller, A    3
7   Smith, J     4
8   Johnson, B   5
9   Lee, M       6
```

But this is only half correct. I want the running total to be based on the day AND client. The table I want looks like this:

```
Day Client       RunningTotal

1   Smith, J     1
3   Johnson, B   1
6   Fuller, A    1
7   Smith, J     2
8   Johnson, B   2
9   Lee, M       1
```

Comment: Mashrur: Welcome to SO. But please pay mind to your formatting with future questions. It would also be helpful to know what flavor of RDBMS you're using. There will be very different approaches to this issue with different DBs.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just need to add `Client` into the JOIN?

```
SELECT a.Day, a.Client, SUM(1) AS RunningTotal
FROM Sales a 
JOIN Sales b ON b.Day <= a.Day and a.Client = b.Client 
GROUP BY a.Day, a.Client
ORDER BY a.Day
```

BTW: This approach to calculating running totals is only really suitable for small input sets. The work required grows exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
Select a.Day, a.Client, SUM(1) AS RunningTotal
From dbo.Sales a, dbo.Sales b
Where b.Day <= a.Day And a.Client = b.Client
Group By a.Day, a.Client
Order By a.Day
```